# Proving that $\int_a^b\frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}\;\mathrm{d}x$ is irrational, given $b - a$ is irrational

Tags: integration, irrational-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I believe - am pretty much certain - that $\int_a^b \frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor} dx$ will  be irrational if $b - a$ is irrational, due to the discrete nature of the floor function's and its reciprocal's rectangles. However, I do not know how this theory would be expressed proof-wise. I've been trying some funky stuff with moduli, but I still struggling expressing my observation, and I don't even know if modular arithmetic is the way to go. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you assuming that $[a,b]\cap (0,1)=\emptyset$?

Comment: I suggest:  look at special cases.  Suppose, for instance, that $a\in \mathbb N$ and $a<b<a+1$.  Can you solve it then?  Can you generalize?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yeah, let's say the lower bound is at least 1.

Comment: Specific hint:  suppose $1<a<2$ and $2<b<3$.  Work out the integral completely  (as a function of $(a,b)$) in this case.  You should have no trouble getting a counterexample to your conjecture.

Comment: As a counter example, $b = 2\sqrt 2$ and $a = \sqrt2$...

Comment: @peterwhy  Somewhat bizarrely, that's the same counterexample I had in mind.  I guess $\sqrt 2$ is the most obvious irrational between $1$ and $2$...

Comment: @lulu But assuming the difference between a and b is irrational, then splitting it into two parts over the point 2 will yield at least one irrational number over a rectangle; and that irrational number times the height of the rectangle will be the integral over the interval [a, 2) or (2, b].  That supports my conjecture, no?

Comment: @peterwhy But the difference between those numbers is the square root of two, which is irrational

Comment: And the question has given that $b-a$ is irrational.

Comment: I suggest that you do the integral explicitly...don't just wave your hands.  Indeed, the two integrals are both irrational, but the sum of two irrationals can be rational, as here.

Comment: @lulu I see now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

...(assuming we don't have to worry about $0$ ... i.e. assuming $0 < a < b$ or equivalent) ...

Well

$\int_a^b \frac 1{\lfloor x \rfloor}dx =$

$\int_a^{\lceil a\rceil}\frac 1{\lceil a\rceil-1}dx + \sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil}^{\lfloor b\rfloor -1}\int_n^{n+1}\frac 1ndx + \int_{\lfloor b\rfloor }^b\frac 1{\lfloor b\rfloor }dx=$

$(\lceil a\rceil - a)\frac 1{\lceil a\rceil-1} + \sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil}^{\lfloor b\rfloor -1}\frac 1n+ (b- \lfloor b\rfloor)\frac 1{\lfloor b\rfloor}=$

$\{\frac b{\lfloor b\rfloor} - \frac a{{\lceil a\rceil}-1}\}+\{\sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil}^{\lfloor b\rfloor -1}\frac 1n +\frac {\lceil a\rceil}{\lceil a\rceil-1}- 1\}$ will be rational if and only if

$\{\frac b{\lfloor b\rfloor} - \frac a{{\lceil a\rceil}-1}\}$ is.

and from there it's probably not to difficult to come up with a counter example.  The only really requirement is that (as $\lfloor b\rfloor$ and $\lceil a \rceil - 1$ are both integers) is that $a$ and $b$ be in a rational proportion to each other (yet themselves irrational).

My attempt:

> If we let $ k-1 < a < k < k+1< b $ we'd have
>     $b - a\cdot(\frac{\lfloor b\rfloor}{{\lceil a\rceil}-1})=$
>
>     $b-a\cdot \frac{k+1}k=b -a - \frac 1k a $ which could be rational if, say,
>
>     $b-a\cdot \frac{k+1}k = 0$
>
>     $b = a\frac {k+1}k$ and $a$ is an arbitrary irrational number and $k$ and arbitrary positive integer.  Then $b- a = \frac 1k a$ is irrational.

Comment: This also means that if $a$,$b$ and $1$ are rationally independent, then the original integral is irrational, right?

Comment: ... maybe.  I'd say so but you have to define what rationally independent means.  It's too easy for me to see getting twisted.  I'd like to say so long as $\frac bk - \frac am$ is irrational for all $k,m\in \mathbb Z$ or so long as $b \ne r\cdot a$ for any rational $r$ this will be true.  I leave the details to the reader (although I am not a thousand percent certain it is true).

Comment: Note that if $a\not\in\mathbb Z$ (that we can assume wlog) then $\lceil a\rceil-1=\lfloor a\rfloor$ so you can simplify your study to $\left(\frac b{\lfloor b\rfloor}-\frac a{\lfloor a\rfloor}\right)$ rationality. The counter example of $a,b$ multiple of the same surd appears better under this form. e.g. $(\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{2})$ or $(3\sqrt{5},4\sqrt{5})$ or $(6\sqrt{13},8\sqrt{13})$. Dunno though if $a/b$ irrational would be an additional sufficient condition.